# Assign value to a variable inside a string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a line in my code which assigns a value to a variable.

```
select @startdate = MIN(Stime) from mytable
```

Now I want to implement my code inside a stored procedure and get tablename as argument. So I changed the code to look like this

```
Set @sql = 'select @startdate = MIN(Stime) from '+@mytable
EXEC (@sql)
```

I'm getting an error which says that `@startdate` variable is not defined. Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I want to assign the `Min(stime)` value to `@startdate`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to stop using `EXEC()` for dynamic SQL. One reason is that for output parameters you need to be able to declare them - a bit tougher for `EXEC()` to handle. But [there are even more important reasons](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql). I assume you are properly sanitizing or validating the value for `@mytable`, wherever it comes from...

```
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'SELECT @startdate = MIN(Stime) FROM ' + @mytable;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@startdate DATETIME OUTPUT', @startdate OUTPUT;

SELECT @startdate;
```